# AWS security group and Django Email SMTP TLS port 587

Tags: django, aws-lambda, smtp, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I am running Django on AWS Lambda with Zappa. I have AWS Lambda set in a VPC and I have an EC2 NAT Instance in the same VPC. The NAT Instance security group takes inbound connections from by Lambda subnets (through HTTPS and HTTP) and outbounds to the public internet. This way, my Django app can communicate with the public internet if it needs to send Push Notifications to Apple Push Notification services.

One thing that does not work is sending emails from Django. It works in development but not on AWS Lambda. I send emails with SMTP using port 587, and I use TLS.

I figured I had to add Inbound rules to my NAT Instance security group. The problem is I can't add inbound SMTP with port 587.

Here are screenshots to show this.

When I select SMTP, the port number is fixed at 25 and greyed out so I can't modify the port to 587. [image]

I looked at other options in the list but none of them set the port number to 587.
[image]

I even tried 'Custom TCP Rule' and setting the port to 587 but that does not work. Emails are not sending! [image]

Comment: You should not be looking at inbound rules, but outbound. The emails are going out, not coming in. And if you did set internet connection for your lambda function, it should work, since your function should be able to talk to the internet using any port.